# Java DB Schema 'TEST' does not exist

Tags: java, javadb

Hy!!!

I want to make a small DB Demo.

My Error is: `Schema 'TEST' does not exist`

Picture:
[image]

Comment: Post the code so that people can read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run a "CREATE SCHEMA TEST" one time to create the schema.

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

perhaps it is to late but it can be useful for other people who read this site to know the solution to this problem.

You have to enable the APP Schema : right klick on APP and then click =>  Set as default Schema

Envoy

Answer (score 1):

I was able to establish a connection with an uninitialized database, using that user, with the following code:

```
package derby;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DerbyTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:testdb;create=true", "test", "test");
    Statement s=connection.createStatement();
    s.execute("create table test_table (name varchar(128))");
    connection.close();
}
}
```

The main difference between your code and mine is that I used the embedded driver, not the network client, and I created a table in the test, of course. I was not able to replicate the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple
 You Have to write
`APP.TEST`
don't write simple `TEST` (as test schema does not exist).

For example you created a table test in database as you show snapshot
then

```
INSERT INTO TEST (.....) STATEMENT
```

will not work.

Instead

```
INSERT INTO APP.TEST (....)
```

will work.